# Using one getStringArray call to different String arrays

Tags: android, xml, string

In the strings.xml file have few String arrays, for example:

```
<string-array name="T1"> //demolitionHammers
    <item>Makita HM1200K</item>
    <item>Makita HM1202C</item>
    <item>Bosch GSH 5E</item>
    <item>Bosch GBH 11DE</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="T2"> //diamondDrills
    <item>Makita DBM080</item>
    <item>Bronco BDD150A</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="T3"> //groundDenser
    <item>Shatal PC2016</item>
</string-array>
```

In the Java file I have a string variable with the name of the wanted array, for example(the wanted array will determine from other activity and will be different each time):

```
String strName = "T2";
```

The problem is that I cant use now the following call to get the specific String-array:

```
String[] selectedSubList = res.getStringArray(R.array.strName);
```

How can this can be done?

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier(strName, "array", getPackageName())`

Comment: String[] selectedSubList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.T1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getIdentifier()` method

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(strName, "array",context.getPackageName());
String[] selectedSubList = res.getStringArray(resId);
```

Comment: I get: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(int)' on a null object reference